# UI to Access/Edit POM.xml properties of Java projects

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, pom.xml

I have multiple maven Java Projects in my system. POM files have release and trunk profiles and within these profiles, there are many properties. I would like to have a UI to display these properties from all the  pom files in my system and if possible, an option to edit these properties.

How can I do it? What I am looking for is, something like an html page which shows all the details I need and can edit them? Or existing add-on in Netbeans/Eclipse?

I use Netbeans IDE.

Comment: Do you use Eclipse M2E ?

Comment: No. I use Netbeans.

Comment: @khmarbaise is there any solution, if it was Eclipse M2E

Comment: Your requirements are unclear. You can open multiple **pom.xml** files in NetBeans, and then have them all visible at the same time using **View > Split** if that helps. But it sounds like you also want some functionality to present the **pom.xml** source(s) in a way other than as XML text. If so, you need to be far more explicit about what you want. As it stands your question is too vague.

Comment: @skomisa thanks for your comment. What I am looking for is, something like an html page which shows all the details I need and can edit them? Or existing add-on in Netbeans/Eclipse? Opening multiple POM files does not help me as there are too many POM files and I want to view only some specific data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you might want something similar to the [GUI POM Editor in Eclipse](http://www.codetab.org/apache-maven-tutorial/manage-eclipse-maven-project/), and NetBeans has no direct equivalent, nor any plugin, which is directly comparable to that. Nor does it offer an "HTML page" for editing. However, it still provides some useful functionality when editing **pom.xml** that might meet your needs. For example:

- NetBeans uses the specified schema definition (XSD) file to provide auto-completion, so if you unsure of the version to specify for the **maven-war-plugin**, position the cursor to the right of the `<version>` tag and press control-space. A list of valid option will be displayed:

  [image: mvnVersion]
- You can generate certain entries by positioning the cursor at a suitable point in the file, and then right-clicking and selecting **Insert Code...** (or press Alt-Insert). A **Generate** context menu will appear:

  [image: mvnGenerate]
- If you select **Dependency...** from the menu the **Add Dependency** dialog will be displayed. Press control-space in the **Group ID** field to get a sorted list of possible values. Repeat in the **Artifact ID** field to get a sorted list of possible values for the chosen **Group ID**, and repeat in the **Version** field to get a list of possible versions for the chosen **Group ID** + **Artifact ID**.

  [image: mvnDependency]
- Clicking the **Effective** tab shows the effective POM:

  [image: mvnEffective]
- Clicking the **Graph** tab shows the a graphical representation of the dependencies in your POM that you can manipulate:

  [image]

Obviously there's more, but that gives you a flavor of what is available when editing **pom.xml** in NetBeans.